# How to run nodejs with html like vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am very new to node so I need help with this one. I understand how to display a html file using nodejs such as this:

(node)

```js
var http = require('http');
let fs = require("fs");


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile("test.html",(err, data) => {
    if(!err) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(data);
    }
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

However, I want to know how I would use this to do things you would do in js such as

(js)

```js
document.getElementById("thisElement").style.backgroundColor = "#234";
document.getElementById("thisElement").addEventListener("click",() => {
 doThings();
});
```

And other related js stuff.

Comment: The client side JavaScript in your second snippet would be run in concert with the HTML itself. The server does not and cannot have anything to do with DOM manipulation directly. Since you would execute JavaScript in the client browser the same exact way as you would if the files were served with any other HTTP server, it's not exactly clear what your question is. "*I want to know how I would use this to do things you would do in js*" ... why not write it in a `<script></script>` block in your HTML file? Why would this change just because you're serving the file with a Node-based HTTP server?

Comment: @esqew I want to do vanilla js inside of node js because I heard that using node you can update, read, delete (i think), and create files such as a json file. But you can't do all that in vanilla js so I wanted to try that in node.

Comment: "*I want to do vanilla js inside of node js*" OK, but just because you *want* to conflate the two doesn't mean it's necessarily possible. Can you share a source upon which you're basing your implicit claim to the contrary? "*I heard that using node you can update, read, delete (i think), and create files such as a json file. But you can't do all that in vanilla js*" You can most certainly generate and manipulate files using browser-based JavaScript. What you *seem* to be after is direct filesystem access, which you are correct in implying is not directly possible in a browser context.

Comment: You need to tell us what your actual goal is. Do you want to create a website? A web app? A CRUD API? Tell us what you want to create and we can tell you how to approach it. Also note that the term "Vanilla JS" is typically used to distinguish *in-browser, client-side* pure JavaScript code from *in-browser, client-side* React / Vue / jQuery / etc JavaScript code. Talking of "Vanilla JS" in the context of a node app doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You need to understand that Node is a purely server-side language. It has absolutely no concept of a DOM like a browser does. You'll need to grasp this concept in order to design a solution that can leverage each as needed to meet the requirements you have. For example, you could write an HTML front-end that collects data in a `<form>` and sends it to your Node.js-based back-end via AJAX (or more rudimentary HTTP request) for your Node server to then parse the information and create/update/delete files within the server's filesystem as your requirements dictate.

Comment: @ChrisG My goal is to create a html file that I can use to store information into json files. I understand that you can create json files, put data into it, and read it in vanilla js. But I also want to update the json file for new data. My goal isn't to create a website or web app or "CRUD API" really.

Comment: @esqew Oh okay, thank you for your help then! I will do more research on node along with http requests like you mentioned.

Comment: The only way to store information permanently with just an html file is to 1) provide a file <input> where you can select the JSON file 2) manually select the JSON file from your hard drive each time 3) let the script in your HTML file make the desired changes 4) start a download containing the altered JSON 5) overwrite the file on your hard drive with the downloaded file. --- For any kind of permanent storage without that convoluted and inelegant way you need a server. Commonly, servers are created using PHP, Python, asp.NET or nodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand how to display a html file using nodejs such as this:

That does not "display an HTML file using nodejs".

That sends an HTML file to a an HTTP client such as a web browser.

A web browser can display an HTML file.

---

> However, I want to know how I would use this to do things you would do in js such as

Web browsers take HTML, generate a DOM, run JavaScript with client-side Web APIs and provide a UI for the user to interact with it.

Node.js doesn't.

---

The JavaScript programming language is a general purpose programming language.

Web browsers provide particular APIs for doing things that are useful to do in a web browser.

Node.js provides APIs for doing things in other contexts (such as running an HTTP server or writing command line utilities).

You can't take JS designed to run in a web browser and run it in Node. It doesn't make sense.

(You can write code which runs in both contexts (generating a random number to take a trivial example) but most code isn't that generic).

Comment: Thank you for the help! If you can't run node js on the client side like you can in vanilla js then is there a way I can run node js functions with parameters using vanilla js? I want to try to update, read, or create json files using node but I can't do all that using vanilla js.

Comment: No. The reason node.js can write files is because it is designed to run on _a_ computer and do that sort of thing. The reason browsers can't is because it would be a security problem if Joe-Random-Website could access the browser owner's filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You see this line on your codes
`fs.readFile("test.html",(err, data) =>` {

this line goes and pick test.html file, which is available on your client side
now, anything relating to this test.html file is a **client thing**
since its html, in it you will declare tags and javascript file references as below

```
<html>
    <body>

    <script src = "../../to/js/files.js"></script>
    <!-- or as below -->
    <script>
      //now in here you get to do your fun stuffs as you asked above
       document.getElementById("thisElement").style.backgroundColor = "#234";
       document.getElementById("thisElement").addEventListener("click",() => {
       doThings();
      });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script file you are trying to run in the public folder and on the backend(Node.js), add this line of code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
```

Note:The javascript you can run here is limited, I think.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do it on this way with node because it's not its purpose, node was made to serve things not to change html or act on browser stuff as you want, there's no DOM on node.

BUT, You can try reading the file and editing it inserting content, but it will be such an hard thing to do once you will need to change the text and it will probably being an array or you can try it with express termplate engine, you can use templates that are mutable when you serve it with node, so you can use variables as html values.

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

Comment: "*node was made to serve things*" I think this statement needs a *lot* more clarity. There are a near-innumerable amount of uses for Node that don't include "*[serving] things*", and to make such a claim is misrepresentative at best.

Comment: Ok, so I should've write more 500 hundred lines to explain what I mean to say? haha, at the end he will need to solve the request with a response, serving a status, a body or anything, but he will need to give a feedback on something...

But he will not do anything with the DOM or something...

Comment: @GabrielPanegrossiSantos Thank you for your help, but I think I got it know.